# Golang Unmarshal XML attributes

Tags: xml, go

I'm trying to get some attribute values out of XML, but without success.
http://play.golang.org/p/a5IqjbH3DV

Can anyone spot of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Note that instead of using `fmt.Print(v)` to check for the values, you can get better output using `fmt.Printf("%#v", v)`, which show the fields and the values. Like this https://play.golang.org/p/DLb1hMmXAe

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The fields should be exported ( start with uppercase )

You did it right for the `Entry` but not for the `Statistics` struct

See: http://play.golang.org/p/cQRGJag313

```
type Statistics struct {
    TotalUploadViews int `xml:"totalUploadViews,attr"`
    SubscriberCount  int `xml:"subscriberCount,attr"`
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, thats so silly of me. I spent like an hour fiddling with structs trying to figure out whats wrong, while missing this fundamental mistake. Im fairly new to Go, good lesson. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, _exported_ is the way the spec talks about it. It also says structs have _fields,_ though, but a struct attribute is close enough.

Comment: @JanNetherdrake Yeap, I had the same problem yesterday but with json.